# I want to propose we open this forum to Blake's Pantheon

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been spending a little time on the new literature site, and they get a sh*t-ton more questions than we do.  We would benefit greatly if we could attract more lit people, as the lit people we currently have tend to be excellent contributors. There are many sci-fi/fantasy fans on lit that read the genre authors heavily influenced by "the classics".

It's true that Blake's mythology tends to be a subject traditionally covered by English Literature, and while that us useful, I'm interested in the analysis of mythographers, which I consider to be the most fundamental.

We do allow Milton, so possibly this is a moot point and Blake is already within our scope.

Comment: Curious, why do you feel Blake's mythology is off topic? Do you have specific questions about Blake's pantheon? Good, then why not just go ahead and ask them?

Comment: Tangentially, although it's certainly good that Lit.SE is getting a lot of questions, if you look a little deeper you'll notice that almost 1 out of 5 of their questions remains unanswered. There are probably a few different things we could try to get people to ask more questions here, however, that won't amount to much if their questions remain unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Go for it, I guess.

But one of the things I've learned on my time on this site is quality over quantity. 1 question that is well thought out, easily understood, thought provoking, and not easily answered goes a lot farther than 5 easily answered by wikipedia.

Also, as @yannis points out, 1/5 of the questions on Lit.SE gets unanswered. They already have 138 unanswered questions, while Myth.SE, having gone through 700 days, only has 86.

But if you have a question, don't wait to ask on meta to ask if it's on-topic; ask it!